# The IE8 do weird on :before and background

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, background

The IE8 do weird on :before and background

I use :before and background to simulate a radio input, the code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <!-- Set the viewport width to device width for mobile -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

  <title>Welcome to Foundation</title>

  <script src="javascripts/modernizr.foundation.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/docs.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">        </script>
  <style>
  #aaa:before {
  width:16px;
  height:16px;
  content:"";
  display:block;
  background: transparent url('img/7.png') -2px -2px no-repeat;
  }
  #aaa.checked:before {
  background-position: -38px -2px;
  }

  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="aaa" onclick='$("#aaa").toggleClass("checked")'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

On the chrome, click on the image, the effect works well, on IE8, there is no effect of first click on image, and second time, it works weird.

Comment: Are you in compatibility mode?

Comment: No, the F12 shows it is in IE8 standard mode, there is no problem when run on IE10 with IE8 standard mode.